# Monoidal functor from Set to $\{0,1\}$.

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, monoidal-categories

The motivation for this question is to find interesting comparison functors between **$1$-category theory** (Set-Categories) and **$0$-category theory** ($\{0,1\}$-categories).

> Are there interesting/known/useful in the literature **monoidal functors** between **Set** and **$\{0,1\}$**?

Comment: By $\{0,1\}$ do you mean the discrete category with two objects, the poset, or something else?  And what monoidal structure are you talking about, the cartesian structure on Set and the "multiplication" structure on $\{0,1\}$?

Comment: I am looking at $\{0,1\}$ as complete poset. Cartesian structure on Set, yes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, there just aren't many functors $\mathbf{Set}\to\{0,1\}$ at all.  First of all, since $\{0,1\}$ is a poset, a functor to it is just determined by where it sends objects.  Moreover, there are no maps $1\to 0$, but there if $X$ and $Y$ are sets, there is a map $X\to Y$ unless $X$ is nonempty and $Y$ is empty.  So if $F:\mathbf{Set}\to\{0,1\}$ is a functor which is not constant, it must send the empty set to $0$ and all nonempty sets to $1$.

Thus there are exactly three functors $\mathbf{Set}\to\{0,1\}$: the constant functor with value $0$, the constant functor with value $1$, and the functor which sends the empty set to $0$ and all other sets to $1$.  If you are considering the cartesian monoidal structures, then the constant functor with value $0$ does not admit any monoidal structure while the other two functors are strictly monoidal.

In the context of turning $\mathbf{Set}$-categories (ordinary categories) into $\{0,1\}$-categories (preorders), the third functor would be the standard one to use.  It takes an ordinary category and it turns it into a preorder by saying $a\leq b$ iff there exists a morphism $a\to b$.